# How can I use python to display nested lists in separate lines in kv label?

Tags: python, list, nested, label, kivy

I have a list of lists, where there are 3 items per inner list (as in the example below).

> data = [
>           ["abe","abo","aba"],
>           ["ade","acd","acr"],
>           ["adr","adw","adz"],
>           ["akw","aky","akz"],
>           ["bad","bbf","btr"],
>           ["bst","bsv","bus"]
>               ]

In the kv file, I have set a Label (inside a ScrollView) to display information from the list when the user presses a given Button.

```
> ScrollView:
      pos_hint_y: 'bottom'
      size_hint_y: 0.65
      id:scroll
      Label:
          id: mylabel
          text: 'Choose a letter to display the list'
          text_size: (self.width, None)
          size_hint_y: None
          height: self.texture_size[1]
          padding_x:20
          valign: ('top')
          halign: ('left')
```

Right now (as is) the label displays the information I want, but in a continuous flow.

```
> def btn_a(self):
    self.l = self.mylabel     # reference to mylabel in kv.file
    self.l.bind(size=lambda s, w: s.setter('text_size')(s, w))    # binding
    a_list = [x for x in self.data if x[0][0] == "a"]    # getting info starting with letter "a"
    self.l.text = str(a_list)  # setting the info inside the label
```

I want the information to be displayed like this:

abe, abo, aba
ade, acd, acr
adr, adw, adz
akw, aky, akz

I've tried to use "\n".join(), tried to flatten the list, use loops and a set of other solutions you'd laugh at... I have very little experience in programming and I'm wanting to learn, but this is getting the sleep out of me. Please, help! How do I separate 3 items per line (without the square brackets, but with commas)?

Comment: @junnytony's solution looks like it should print in the way you want to terminal.

If you want to know why your buttons are in one line instead of new lines, I don't see any code in what you've shown us that indicates you would create a new line anywhere.

Comment: In the kv.file, I have a Button which triggers (on_press: root.btn_a()) the btn_a function in the main.py. I guess I should have explained that I assigned @junnytony 's suggestion to: lis = "\n".join(["%s, %s, %s" % (a, b, c) for a, b, c in data]). Then changed the following: self.l.text = str(lis). Although I had tried several pieces of code, I didn't include them in the question because they didn't work. Maybe I should have, to show what I was doing wrong...sorry.

Comment: What I meant was that it doesn't seem like the problem you're having is related to the code you've shown us...
I mean, it looks like you want to make a gui (in a browser?--again, not at all familiar with kv), in which case you need to define a separation in lines for your buttons through kv or something similar. Simply adding '\n' (new line character for strings) won't necessarily do anything if I understand your problem correctly. If it's a webpage, then you need the <br> tag. If kv has it's own new-line syntax, or needs a new group, then I'd look up that--like how PySide QtGui needs layouts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your data is as you specified, this should do the trick:

```
"\n".join(["%s, %s, %s" % (a, b, c) for a, b, c in data])
```

will produce a list where each line has 3 strings separated by comma's.

EDIT: For completeness, this can also be done more generically as:

```
"\n".join([", ".join(entry) for entry in data])
```

This will work for lists or lists where the internal lists can be of any length.

Comment: This works really well. In case it helps other people, my mistake was to try to target every third item in the list with the "\n".join(item[2]..., which obviously didn't work.

Comment: I should mention here that, since the purpose of my question was to set the text inside the label (and not to "print" to the console), I had to assign the suggestion (before the last line of the btn_a function), like: lis = "\n".join(["%s, %s, %s" % (a, b, c) for a, b, c in data]). Then, changed the last line of the btn_a function from: self.l.text = str(a_list)  to: self.l.text = str(lis)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about 'kivy' and the UI-views aspect of your result, but as a matter of just printing the desired string, you could do:

```
for triplet in data:
    print(', '.join(triplet))
```

If you want that as a string rather than printed to the console, you could do:

```
composed_string = '\n'.join([', '.join(triplet) for triplet in data])
print(composed_string)
```

Comment: It works very well. As I don't want to print to the console, but set the text inside the label, I used, as you suggested, the for loop to create the string (composed_string). Hope this helps other people, too.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternate version that you can try just so you can practice manipulating lists in different ways:

```
for x in data:
    for y in x:
        print y,
    print "\n",
```

Note that the comma at the end of the print statement prevents it from adding a new line it self, as it usually does

alternately again, you could do it in a weird hackey way and try printing nothing (or a space) and that will add the newline you need to separate the list of lists.

```
for x in data:
    for y in x:
        print y,
    print
```

I know this isn't the best method; I'm just trying to show there are always other ways of solving a problem. And it can be good practice for early learners to practice trying to find various solutions. It's also good to be aware of what print does re `\n` and that little comma trick.